# Doing Sum and Mean on different columns to generate a grand total in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a dataframe, something like

```
name perc score
a    0.2   40
b    0.4   89
c    0.3   90
```

I want to have a total row where 'perc' has a mean aggregation and 'score' has a sum aggregation. The output should be like

```
  name perc score
    a    0.2   40
    b    0.4   89
    c    0.3   90
  total  0.3  219
```

I want it as a dataframe output as I need to build plots using this. For now, I tried doing

```
df.loc['total'] = df.sum()
```

but this provides the sum for the percentage column as well, whereas I want an average for the percentage. How to do this in pandas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is already answered somewhere in SO but it was faster to just write the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df.loc['total'] = [df['perc'].mean(), df['score'].sum()]
```

Output:

```
       perc  score
name              
a      0.20   40.0
b      0.40   89.0
c      0.30   90.0
total  0.30  219.0
```

Comment: yes, the output is straight from my console :)

Comment: Nice and simple answer!

Answer (score 0):

If it is more convenient to slice the columns, you can do the following:

(summing the first column `a` (0) and the mean for columns `b` and `c` (1 and 2))

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        'b':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 
        'c':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
    }
)
```

```
   a   b    c
0  1  10  100
1  2  20  200
2  3  30  300
3  4  40  400
4  5  50  500
```

```
df.loc['total'] = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:1].sum(), df.iloc[:,1:].mean()])
```

```
          a     b      c
0       1.0  10.0  100.0
1       2.0  20.0  200.0
2       3.0  30.0  300.0
3       4.0  40.0  400.0
4       5.0  50.0  500.0
total  15.0  30.0  300.0
```